# How can I see if a contact has video/voice capability in Empathy?

Tags: icons, empathy

I'm using empathy for the first few weeks now on Ubuntu 12.10.

I can't find any symbols indicating a contact has the ability to do a video chat or voice chat...

Though I can see a "Mobile" symbol which say "Online from a mobile or Phone device".

PS: I can see a video call, Audio call option enables when I right click on a particular contact.

I don't see any option to configure anything like that.

OS : Ubuntu 12.10

Gnome 3.6.1 (PPA)

Empathy : 3.6.0.3

Answer (score 0):

empathy uses the farstream library to enable audio and video and as far as I can tell it's not available in the 12.10 repositories. I'm also trying to find a way to enable it.